# Returning event handler function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
closeButton.onclick = (function(box){
    return function(evt){box.display = 'none';};
})(msgBox);
```

I would like to return a function which will execute on the button click. Is this correct? If not, how it should be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example works and is using [currying](http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-curry/), but you could easily do without it. Since `msgBox` is available in the current scope, you can reference it within the function which will create a closure for `msgBox`.

```
closeButton.onclick = function(event) {
    msgBox.display = 'none';
};
```